# MySQL X Dev API: session.sql is not a function

Tags: node.js, mysql-connector

Using [@mysql/xdevapi](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/) I'm attempting to retrieve the results of a raw SQL query but I'm getting the following error:

```
{"message":"Error validating selections: s.sql is not a function","level":"error"}
```

I'm following the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/using-sql.html) but I can't understand why I'm getting this error.

The failing code is below ...

```
const mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi')
const logger = require('./logger')

const {
  MYSQL_USER,
  MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  MYSQL_HOST,
  MYSQL_PORT,
  MYSQL_SCHEMA
} = process.env

const session =  mysqlx.getSession({
  user: MYSQL_USER,
  password: MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  host: MYSQL_HOST,
  port: parseInt(MYSQL_PORT)
})
.catch(e => logger.error('Error connecting to database:', e))

exports.validateSelections = selections =>
  session
    .then(s => s
      .getSchema(MYSQL_SCHEMA)
      .sql('SELECT * FROM affiliate_links WHERE id = 1')
      .execute()
    )
```

And the calling code ...

```
const { body } = require('express-validator/check')
const { validateSelections } = require('../database')
const postcodeValidator = require('postcode-validator');
const logger = require('../logger')
const config = require('../../config/config')

module.exports = [
  body('postcode')
    .custom(postcode => {
      const isValid = postcodeValidator.validate(postcode, 'UK')
      logger.info(`Postcode value passed into postcode validator: ${postcode}`)
      if(!isValid) {
        return Promise.reject(config.errors.invalid_postcode)
      }
      return Promise.resolve()
    }),

  body('selections')
    .custom(selections => {
      logger.info(`Selections passed into validator: ${selections.toString()}`)

      if (!Array.isArray(selections)) {
        logger.debug('Selections is not an array')
        Promise.reject(config.errors.invalid_survey_selection)
      }

      validateSelections(selections)
        .then(result => {
          // Check result and resolve
          Promise.resolve()
        })
        .catch(e => {
          logger.error(`Error validating selections: ${e.message}`)
          Promise.reject(config.errors.invalid_survey_selection)
        })
      })
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.sql()` method is available at the `Session` level, not at the `Schema` level. Also, not sure if you are doing it already but you would want to attach a `catch()` handler by the end of the promise chain, otherwise you will loose errors thrown after the `getSession()` call, which is what is happening in this case.

In any case, you want to do one of the following (using your own pattern):

**Specifying the schema in the query itself**

```
exports.validateSelections = selections =>
  session
    .then(s => s
      .sql(`SELECT * FROM ${MY_SCHEMA}.affiliate_links WHERE id = 1`)
      .execute()
    )
```

**Switching to the given schema before running the query**

```
exports.validateSelections = selections =>
  session
    .then(s => s
      .sql(`USE ${MY_SCHEMA}`)
      .execute()
      .then(() => s
        .sql('SELECT * FROM affiliate_links WHERE id = 1')
        .execute()
      )
    )
```